# Given a MPEG DASH .mpd URL, is that possible to down all media segments through youtube_dl?

Tags: download, mpeg-dash, youtube-dl

I'm looking for a MPEG DASH downloader and youtube_dl just hit on me.

Given a [.mpd URL](http://gce-bitbucket.storage.googleapis.com/bitStorage/2_6f9d0adade5b9d4547d0ac6ae436ae9c/546_Sintel.2010.720p.mkv/mpds/Sintel.2010.720p.mkv.mpd), is that possible to use youtube_dl to download all media segments then?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To download all video and audio segments and mux them into a single file, call [`youtube-dl`](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) thus:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio http://URL/TO/manifest.mpd
```

The option `-f <id1>[,<id2>]...` is used to select which stream (or streams) of segments to save. The `-f bestvideo+bestaudio` in this example makes youtube-dl save only the best video and audio streams. See [format selection syntax](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection) for details and more advanced format selectors. In order to discover the available streams, use `youtube-dl -F http://URL/TO/manifest.mpd`.

In order to mux (merge) video and audio streams into a single file, you must have [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) or [libav](https://libav.org/) installed in your system. Otherwise, youtube-dl will produce a separate file for each stream (in my example, one for audio and one for video).

Without explicit format selection, the default is `-f bestvideo+bestaudio/best`. Youtube-dl will automatically select the best video and audio, and if there are no separate video-only or audio-only streams, the best stream that contains both video and audio is selected.

```
youtube-dl http://URL/TO/manifest.mpd
```

This default is used since version 2015.04.26. Before that (or if `-o -` is specified, making youtube-dl write output to stdout), the default was `-f best`, ignoring the video-only and audio-only streams. You may want to specify `-f best` explicitly when separate video and audio have worse quality than a stream that has both.

Comment: In my case, only manually specifying the bestvideo+bestaudio switch resulted in actually downloading the video.

Comment: I added more details on the default format selector. Which version of youtube-dl did you use, @JeroenBaert?

Comment: @Palec : I don't remember, but it's fixed in the latest version now :)

Comment: Is it possible to specify a local .mpd file?