# Is it possible to find mpd url/file for a YouTube video?

Tags: python, youtube, manifest

After a long research, I can't find a way to get the mpd url for a YouTube video. My question is, is it even possible to get it?

In theory, YouTube has to have a manifest file, so that it could play out the segment files. My research has led to some old posts where people have allegedly found a way to do it. [A python script that is supposed to extract the mpd file.](https://github.com/ChristianKreuzberger/extract-youtube-mpd) After analyzing, what exactly it is done, I have found that line 68, he is looking for a *dashmpd*, which is not contained in the code. I thought maybe the name of the parameter is changed, and tried to look for some URL, but without success.

```
mpdurl = html[html.find("dashmpd"):]
```

[Topic where MPD file is used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942278/how-to-play-mpd-file), [another similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846530/given-a-mpeg-dash-mpd-url-is-that-possible-to-down-all-media-segments-through/39931712#39931712).

So again, my question is is it even possible to extract the mpd url/file from a YouTube video? Or is it encrypted and not possible any more? Does it make a difference if the video is in *webm* or *mp4* format?

Comment: Check https://github.com/nficano/pytube